# Kotlin compiler error: Unresolved local class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I didn't find solution from my problem with Kotlin compiler.

My Kotlin version (from gradle) - `kotlin_version = '1.2.31'`

This is my code (part of code):

```
private val transitionListener = object : Transition.TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
        showContentAfterTransition()
    }

    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition) {
    }

    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition) {
    }

    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {
        showContentAfterTransition()
    }

    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
    }
}
```

And this is error from Kotlin compiler:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unresolved local class: ua/com/myapp/screen/base/AbsMvpTransitionFragment$transitionListener$1
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:483)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.NotFoundClasses.getClass(NotFoundClasses.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer$typeConstructor$1.invoke(TypeDeserializer.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.typeConstructor(TypeDeserializer.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.simpleType(TypeDeserializer.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.type(TypeDeserializer.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.type$default(TypeDeserializer.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer.loadProperty(MemberDeserializer.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:146)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.access$computeProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:483)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getContributedVariables(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedVariables(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:230)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope.getContributedVariables(SubstitutingScope.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.computeNonDeclaredProperties(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:250)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.access$computeProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:483)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getContributedVariables(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedVariables(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:230)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.addFunctionsAndProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeDescriptors(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:180)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:209)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:221)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope$_allDescriptors$2.invoke(SubstitutingScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope$_allDescriptors$2.invoke(SubstitutingScope.kt:30)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope.get_allDescriptors(SubstitutingScope.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope.getContributedDescriptors(SubstitutingScope.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.computeExtraDescriptors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$extraDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$extraDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorUtils.getAllDescriptors(DescriptorUtils.java:585)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.resolveMemberHeaders(LazyClassDescriptor.java:569)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:539)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:535)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:160)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:451)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:218)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:527)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:909)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:939)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:908)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:407)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the exact type of your variable or remove the  `private`modifier.

```
private val transitionListener: Transition.TransitionListener = object : Transition.TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
        showContentAfterTransition()
    }

    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition) {
    }

    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition) {
    }

    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {
        showContentAfterTransition()
    }

    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
    }
}
```

it seems there is a weird bug in kotlin that make type inference not working in this case.

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467133/3998402)